# How to make a bootstrap column scrollable horizontally

Tags: bootstrap-4, horizontal-scrolling

I want to make `.right-col` scrollable horizontally (`float-div` elements must not be wrapped)

```
<main class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto left-col">
            it's actually the sidebar
        </div>
        <div class="col right-col">
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-right float-div">here is main content which is float</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `d-flex flex-nowrap` on the `col`, and `text-nowrap` on the divs...

```
<main class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto left-col">
            it's actually the sidebar
        </div>
        <div class="col right-col d-flex flex-nowrap">
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
            <div class="float-div text-nowrap">here is main content which is float</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

[Responsive demo](https://codeply.com/p/EGCGKDKuo8)